# ASP.NET Session_End Event and Getting User IP Address

Tags: asp.net, session

In my ASP.NET web application I have my Session_End event in Global.asax. What I would like is to be able to get the IP address of the user. What I have tried is

```
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ip1 = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
    string ip2 = Request.UserHostAddress;
}
```

But Request is null in both cases. How can I get the user's IP address?

Comment: you cannot, since when the `Session_End` fires, there is no client request for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A user's IP address can be retrieved using:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress
```

But as you see, the IP address is retrieved from the "Current.Request", which is not the case with Session_End event since it is not a request. If you specifically need the IP address at Session_End, you can try saving the IP address into a session variable at Session_Start instead and then call for it at Session_End.

Comment: Can you access session from Session_End (Never tried so I actually don't know)?  I believe the HttpContext.Current might be null.  Is there another way to access session?

Comment: HttpContext.Current will be null, but you can access the session simply by Session["MyKey"]

Comment: Yes, you can access session from Session_End as it is "ending" but hasn't been destroyed at this point. I have a few web apps where I store things such as lead captures into the session and wait for the user to convert to a member. If they don't, I move their lead captures from session into my db - this also includes their IP address which I capture at session start.

Comment: I was hoping for a simpler way, but saving the IP address to the session will also work. thanks